# watch not work with "pkill ffmpeg; ffmpeg -i"

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, watch-command

Im using ffmpeg to record online stream. I want to record in small pieces 
with killing ffmpeg process and starting again. Trying to do it with command 
`watch -n 40 "pkill ffmpeg; ffmpeg -i http://SiteName.com/playlist.m3u8 radioSTREAM.$(date +%d-%m-%g-%Hh%Mm%Ss).mp3"` but it stucking. How to make it work ?

Additional question is how to put all this construction in `at` command?

Comment: Consider stream copying the audio with `-c:a copy` instead of re-encoding it.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: It wasn't a solution to whatever issue you're experience, but an unrelated suggestion.

Comment: Oh thank you. For video+audio stream it  `-c:v copy  -c:a copy`  or i can do `-c:v:a copy`?

Comment: You can use `-c copy` if you want to stream copy both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant solution is to use the [segment muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment):

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy -f segment -segment_time 40 output_%03d.mp3
```

Results in approximately 40 second segments:

```
$ ls -m1
output_000.mp3
output_001.mp3
...
output_010.mp3
```

The example avoids re-encoding by using [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode, and assumes the input and output formats are the same (MP3 in this example).

Comment: This is it. Watch usage even not needed here. Though naming here not working that good. Ffmpeg segements thing refusing to work if not put somewhere in filename the `%03d` and `$(date +%d-%m-%g-%Hh%Mm%Ss)` wiriting in name of segment same as in the first segment. But this not that important. Thanks for the solution.                                            Still curious how to make through the `watch`

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a shell script so that you have less tricky escaping, you can the also run that shell script from the at command

If you run the shell script as follows

```
bash -x ./script.sh
```

You will see what values the variables have at each point in the script.

Comment: With script working but not perfect. Now command is `watch -n 60 bash -x ./rstream.sh` The time interval in `watch -n 60` not always giving me 60 second length files, it can also be 40 or 50 seconds length. And its not works when I put in `at`. And if there is way to run this without script ?

Comment: Ffmpeg will take a few seconds to start so I guess you might have to make the segments overlap to ensure you don't loose data.

Comment: It is not ffmpeg. I use ffmpeg in at and recording starts in the required time. I think it is `pkill ffmpeg`, in script its demanding sudo pass, messing couple of seconds or more and starts anyway. Changing to `sudo pkill ffmpeg` didnt helped with delay too.